# ¿Existe el método GetPixel en html con Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Me gustaría saber si existe algún método cómo GetPixel de Visual Basic . NET en Canvas de HTML para hacer filtros que no sean los estándares de grises, negativo, etc... que ya existen.
Me gustaría saber si hay algún método de acceder al pixel de un control Canvas que tenga una imagen cargada en el Canvas en HTML o JavaScript y Poder Acceder a sus Pixeles de Color.

Aquí Muestro un Posible Método Accediendo al Contexto del Canvas...

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#333"></canvas>


//Posible Método en Javascript 
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//var UnColor = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, se puede acceder a los datos de los pixeles: el contexto tiene un método [`getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) para obtener los datos de la imagen, y su valor de retorno ([objeto ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData))tiene una propiedad `data`, que es un array con los datos de color de los pixeles

Por ejemplo, el [color de un solo pixel](https://jsfiddle.net/7c1swtym/):

```js
function getPixelColor(x, y) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  return ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
}
```

Esta función de devuelve un `Uint8ClampedArray` con los valores RGBA del pixel (x, y)